# Triple loop in R

Tags: r, tree

I have four nodes in a tree representing vectors and a distance function that calculates the distance between any node and a divergence point between two other nodes. I would like to implement the following:

```
for all i, for all j, for all k
calculate distance(i,j,k) s.t. k != j != i.
```

So for each of four `i`'s as the main nodes, I would like to get three distances.
For example, taking node 1 as the main node, I want: `(1-->2,3)`, `(1,-->2,4)`, `(1-->3,4)`.

`(1-->2,3)` and `(1-->3,2)`, for instance, would be the same value, but `(1-->2,3)` and `(2-->1,3)`, are not, because there is a different main node.

I tried making a `3D array` as follows and then storing the values in a nested loop but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
 a <- array(rep(1, 4*4*4), dim=c(4, 4, 4))

for (main in 1:4){
  for (i in 1:4) {
    if (i != main){
      for (j in 1:4){
        if (j != main & j != i){
      a[main,i,j] <- sqrt( dist(main,i)*dist(main,j) / dist(i,j))}}}}}
```

Comment: Your code sample is failing, what is `dist`?

Comment: I think its the `dist` function from the vstats` package, but the arguments are not correct and throwing an error. This would work: `dist(c(main,i))`

Comment: No, it is a custom function into which two vectors are fed.